# Scikit Learn: Logistic Regression model coefficients: Clarification

Tags: python, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I need to know how to return the logistic regression coefficients in such a manner that I can generate the predicted probabilities myself.

My code looks like this:

```
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(training_data, binary_labels)

# Generate probabities automatically
predicted_probs = lr.predict_proba(binary_labels)
```

I had assumed the lr.coeff_ values would follow typical logistic regression, so that I could return the predicted probabilities like this:

```
sigmoid( dot([val1, val2, offset], lr.coef_.T) )
```

But this is not the appropriate formulation. Does anyone have the proper format for generating predicted probabilities from Scikit Learn LogisticRegression?
Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

take a look at the documentations (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), offset coefficient isn't stored by lr.coef_

> coef_ array, shape = [n_classes-1, n_features]     Coefficient of the
>   features in the decision function. coef_ is readonly property derived
>   from raw_coef_ that follows the internal memory layout of liblinear.
>   intercept_    array, shape = [n_classes-1]    Intercept (a.k.a. bias) added
>   to the decision function. It is available only when parameter
>   intercept is set to True.

try:

```
sigmoid( dot([val1, val2], lr.coef_) + lr.intercept_ )
```

Comment: #prgao, thanks ,but your answer only tells me how NOT to generate the probabilities. Do you know how to compute them? Thanks.

Comment: sigmoid( dot([val1, val2], lr.coef_) + lr.intercept_ )

Comment: #prgao, that did it. Damn, I figured this would have worked `sigmoid( dot([val1, val2, 1], lr.coef_.T))`, but it turns out, I need to include the intercept twice, as in: `sigmoid( dot([val1, val2, 1], lr.coef_.T) + lr.intercept_ )`. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: It can be shortened to: `sigmoid( dot([val1, val2, 2], lr.coef_.T) )`. Note the `2` value. This effectively adds an additional intercept term.

Comment: Just in case this is useful to someone. I was trying this and I was getting different values from the predict_proba results and the solution proposed by prgao. It turns out I was not normalizing my probabilities (dividing by the sum).

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is by calling `coef_` attribute of LR classifier:

Definition of `coef_` please check [Scikit-Learn document](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html):

See example:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

clf = LogisticRegression()  
clf.fit(x_train,y_train)  

weight = classifier.coef_
```